# unable to start "jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" jdk version "jdk1.7.0_80" netbeans8.1and windows 8

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss7.x

Calling "E:\java\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"

## "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: E:\java\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java

## JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

00:41:36,306 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
00:41:36,838 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
00:41:36,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
00:41:38,447 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '”' (code 8221 / 0x201d) in start tag Expected a quote at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [105,20] at   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:784) at  org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:333) at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '”' (code 8221 / 0x201d) in start tag Expected a quote
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [105,20] at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639) at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3005) at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2926) at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2802) at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125) at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:185) at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:165)
org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:776) ... 13 more
00:41:38,478 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
00:41:38,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 1ms
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You've got a syntax error in one of your XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final] at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:185) at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:165)
```

Based on this message, it seems you modified/added a datasource in XML (standalone-full.xml/standalone-full-ha.xml), which is not valid.

Comment: thanks. i found it use single quote for string instead of double quote.

Comment: @user3311231: Glad answer helped! Good luck.

Comment: @user3311231: It seems you are new user, you should start accepting appropriate answers for all your questions.